# How can I PIVOT rows with different number of values?

Tags: sql, pivot

```
TITLE                   CODE
--------------------------------
ABCDE-AA-XXX-PD-001     A
ABCDE-AA-XXX-PD-001     B
ABCDE-AA-XXX-PD-001     C
ABCDE-AA-XXX-PD-001     D
GBSRH-AF-DXY-PD-001     1
GBSRH-AF-DXY-PD-001     2
GBSRH-AF-DXY-PD-001     3
GBSRH-AF-DXY-PD-001     4
GBSRH-AF-DXY-PD-001     5
GBSRH-AF-DXY-PD-001     6

TITLE                   REVISIONS
-----------------------------------------------------------
ABCDE-AA-XXX-PD-001     A      B      C      D 
GBSRH-AF-DXY-PD-001     1      2      3      4     5     6
```

Comment: This is not how I wrote the question. It's messed up.
Apologies BUT I can't delete it.

Comment: I've formatted your request. You can use the `{}` button to format code and sample data. Or even use a tool like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to format tables.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? I see three options: Either make this one string column with a list ('A, B, C, D' / ',1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6') or provide as many columns as you consider necessary (e.g. 100 columns, because you are sure there will never be more than 100 entries per title) or let your app or Website deal with it - after all it's a display issue, and display issues should be dealt with in your GUI layer, not in the DBMS.

Comment: thanks for formatting my question. much appreciated!